# Экранная клавиатура не появляется при фокусировке поля ввода в Windows 10 (планшет)

Tags: delphi, windows-10, vcl

Есть Windows-приложение, написанное на Delphi, у него есть форма логина. Там поле для ввода логина, и поле для ввода пароля.

Если тапнуть на поле для ввода пароля, то экранная клавиатура поднимается. 
Если тапнуть на поле ввода логина - то нет. То же самое со всеми другими полями, кроме поля ввода пароля. Как Windows различает разные контролы для ввода, и как можно поправить проблему? В Win 7 всё было хорошо.

**upd:** Забавно, проблема пропала сама собой после автообновления Windows.

Comment: Какие компоненты используются для ввода пароля и логина?

Comment: TcxMaskEdit в обоих случаях.

Comment: Свойства у обоих компонентов выставлены *одинаково*? Небольшой трюк: если есть возможность, то попробуйте заменить данные компоненты на стандартные `TMaskEdit` и посмотреть их в работе. В случае отсутствия положительной реакции - обратитесь в техподдержку поставщика компонент (DevExpress, если не путаю?).